# How to output the currently playing file to a text file in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

Is there a way to have a nowplaying.txt file of some sort that contains the currently playing file from Rhythmbox?

I noticed a few plugins here and there for this, but none of them work (they seem to be outdated or just not working at all, despite trying to fix them here and there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I coded a small Java app which covers my needs (it uses the `rhythmbox-client --print-playing` command and writes the output to `~/.rbplay`. The command is called and the output written every 3 seconds. The following code is available under CC-0.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class RBPlay
{

private JFrame frame;
private JLabel lblNewLabel;
private static RBPlay instance;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, InvocationTargetException
{
    EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                instance = new RBPlay();
                instance.frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".rbplay");
    f.createNewFile();
    while(true)
    {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rhythmbox-client --print-playing");
        p.waitFor();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
            fw.write(line);
            fw.close();
            instance.lblNewLabel.setText(line);
        }
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}

public RBPlay()
{
    initialize();
}

private void initialize()
{
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JLabel lblCurrentSong = new JLabel("Current song : ");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblCurrentSong, BorderLayout.WEST);

    lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JLabel lblCloseThisWindow = new JLabel("Close this window to stop RBPlay");
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblCloseThisWindow, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.pack();
}

}
```

Note : this code is not optimized at all. It's just a quick thing I wrote, but hey, it works!